# PIL: Cannot create image from array

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the following code:

```
im = Image.open("image.png")
im_out = im.convert("RGBA").resize((256,256))

image_data = np.asarray(im_out)
print(image_data.shape)
ni = Image.fromarray(image_data)

image_data2 = np.asarray(im_out.getdata())

image_data2 =image_data2.reshape(image_data.shape)

Image.fromarray(image_data2) # Error on this line
```

Why can I create an Image from the first case but not the second, despite them being exactly the same?

I am getting:
`TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 4), <i4`

Comment: Check the `dtype` of the array you created at `image_data2 = np.asarray(...)` I mean `print(image_data2.dtype)`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I hadn't realised the data type changed